# Linux to Samba Automatical Password Synchonization

Tags: linux, passwords, automation, samba, perl

Nothing found at all on the Net: I'm looking up for an automatical synchonization of linux to samba (NOT Samba to Linux) passwords.
I wrote a cgi web form that changes this password directly in the shadow file, using a crypted password (for security reasons I do not want to allow the passwords being stored in cleartext in the logfiles). Not using LDAP. All would be fine if the user logs in for a first time using ssh, but I have users that only use windows, so I cannot ask i.ex. a secretary to do that.

Basically, what I yet did is this:
vi /etc/pam.d/common-password

```
password        required                        pam_smbpass.so nullok use_authtok use_first_pass
```

- I also tried changepassword-0.9, but there is a bug that has never been solved by its programmer.
- Swat is not a solution to me.

I yet found the following sites, but still struggeling around...

-http://uranus.chrysocome.net/linux/smbfs/pam_smbpass.html

-https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/Configuring_a_Samba_Server-Encrypted_Passwords.html

here some code of my perl cgi script:

```
# Crypt the password here so that it cannot be read in any logflie
my $cryptedShadowString = `echo "$new_passwd1"|openssl passwd -1 -stdin`;
chomp($cryptedShadowString);
(...)
open($result, '-|') || exec $SUDO, $EXECUTINGSCRIPT, $login, $old_passwd, $cryptedShadowString, $cryptedShadowString;
```

This will send the encrypted password to another perl script that writes it directly into the shadow file. (All the stuff is shibboleth protected, so I don't care about hackers coming from around the world).

I tried something like that in the execution script, but unfortunately it is not the solution:

```
    # Do a first login to chat the new password to the samba password file:
sleep 2; # sleep a bit, for the next command:
system(" ( echo '') | exec '/bin/su' $login");
```

I cannot use neither AD, samba as DC or LDAP because of non technical company policy reasons.

Someone can help me?
Thx.

Comment: I found this, perhaps it's of help: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/126319-install-samba-so-the-samba-and-pam-passwords-remain-synchronized

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the good direction, I also found the following infos: 
https://books.google.ch/books?id=IQu1YDg_ajwC&pg=PA392&lpg=PA392&dq=smbpasswd+actualization+from+shadow&source=bl&ots=gGBVAOo7Np&sig=9usXskGnF9oWBz9-9YRNNSrtdyo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix8dqZ8InQAhXCOBQKHSKBBDIQ6AEIUzAE#v=onepage&q=smbpasswd%20actualization%20from%20shadow&f=false

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996277

I continue trying, because it still does not work. Maybe there is a samba specialist in the forum..